# How to create many author's page?

Tags: author, author-template

I have template author.php, but I need more pages for every author. For example another page with author's posts with it's own template and url.
How can I do this? Without plugins is better.

UPD: current author's page url: site.com/profile/name. Need pages like site.com/profile/name/posts, site.com/profile/name/photo.

Comment: You mean like [`author-{nicename}.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#author-display) that changes based on the author?

Comment: @Sally CJ  no, common page for all authors like author.php

Comment: You can always create a Page then assign it to a custom template which displays the author's posts. But I'm a little confused with the URL part. Can you give an example? How is it different from the standard author's archive URL (e.g. `example.com/author/admin`)?

Comment: Oh you don't want an author template, but instead a page that lists all authors?

Comment: Not sure but sounds like you want to have more than one page for an author to display different content on them and possibly the template feature to customize layout and other stuffs based on the author?

Comment: @guido more than one page for an author. url like example.com/author/admin/posts or example.com/author/admin/photo

Comment: @redale, in that case, you would want to use the rewrite API, but you can use the same template (`author.php`) to display different content based on the URL.